# What text editor to use while ssh using mac terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, text-editor

I am using my Mac Terminal to SSH into my GoDaddy hosting account.

I was wondering what text editor I could use through Terminal? I am not familiar with VIM or emacs at all so it's hard for me to use.

I've used gedit on Linux and quite like it. I wonder if I could install gedit on the Godaddy server?

Any advice would be appreciated. I am very new to working with SSH and the terminal.

Comment: You can probably just use a Mac OS X editor such as BBEdit which supports SFTP etc and edit the remote files directly on your Mac.

Comment: learn to use VI - it's good for'ya!  :)

Comment: gedit is not a command-line editor. If you already have a remote X session, you can run all kinds of things. If not, gedit won't help you. And it's probably easier to set up BBEdit (or even Aquamacs with Tramp mode) than to set up X tunneling over ssh.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the tip. I didn't know you can do that with BBEdit. I don't have BBEdit though. Maybe I should get it?

Comment: @abarnert Yes I am aware that gedit is not a command-line editor. I've ssh-ed -X before to use gedit. But I couldn't do that on GoDaddy, so hence my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of full-screen text editors, but if you want to edit files locally on your Mac and while ssh'd into a remote server without having to think about it, you really have to learn one of the ubiquitous editors.

In fact, ideally you should learn the basics of all three—at least how to get out safely—because at some point, you're going to accidentally visudo with VISUAL unset or set wrong and find yourself in the wrong editor.

- nano (and its relatives in the pico family) is by far the easiest to learn if you're coming from a TextEdit/TeachText/Notepad background. However, it's the least ubiquitous, and the least efficient with both keystrokes and screen real estate, and real Unix geeks will laugh at you if they ask "vi or emacs" and you say "nano".
- vi (and its relatives—in fact, usually you're using vim, not vi) is the most ubiquitous, and by far the most efficient for quick and simple edits. It's also much more usable from bizarre terminals like your favorite iPad ssh client (where hitting ^X is a major chore). And ultimately, most vi key sequences also work with ed and sometimes even sed, which is really handy when you're stuck on a terminal with full-screen support at all. However, it is by far the hardest to learn when you've coming from a GUI background—the idea that you can't enter or edit text in your text editor except by entering special modes is just weird.
- emacs (and its relatives and simplified clones, like jove and ue) is the most efficient for doing complex operations. It's also nice that its weirder keystrokes (like ^A-F for cursor movement) are the same as the Terminal command line, libreadline, native Mac GUI text controls, and Firefox text controls. And if you really learn emacs, you can start using Aquamacs in the GUI, and programming it to automate all your tedious text editing, and so on. The only problem is that really learning emacs will take you years, and you might have other things to do with your life.

Comment: Why is this question considered off topic, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: @TriNguyen: I didn't vote to close it, so keep in mind that I'm just guessing other people's motivations. But… there is nothing in your question even remotely about programming. It's either about editing configuration files on a server, or editing text in general, or what you're allowed to install on GoDaddy servers. So, it probably belongs on superuser, serverfault, or some other site, not on stackoverflow, which is for programming questions. If you read the FAQ link in the "closed" box, it explains this pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! What you said makes sense. I was a new user to Stackoverflow and wasn't aware of all the other sites and their purposes.

Comment: GNU Readline is the utility responsible for Emacs-like key-bindings in Bash etc. Type `man readline` in search engine or terminal.

Comment: @BradyTrainor: First, I'm not sure why you think that's relevant here. But, more importantly, it's not true. The question is about OS X. GNU Readline is, as the name implies, part of the GNU userland that Linux uses, not part of the BSD userland that OS X uses. In OS X, you have `libedit` instead of `libreadline`, and `man readline` will just say "No manual entry for readline".

Comment: :blush: Oh, you even mentioned that in your answer, I thought I was adding something (accurate), many pardons. Just now I try googling to learn about OS X and (lib)readline, I find nothing, curious... I'm sure it's there, just maybe noone acknowledges it much? (Relevancy was that everyone should be aware of the cool readline keys. But I overlooked that you said this.)

Comment: @BradyTrainor: No, GNU readline really isn't there. `ls -l /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib` will show you that it's just a symlink to `libedit.dylib`. If Apple included it and linked non-GPL applications to it without acknowledging it, that would be a serious violation of the license. Of course you can always install it yourself, or install third-party apps that use it (e.g., some non-python.org Python distributions for OS X include a statically-linked GNU readline).

Comment: don't really agree with the suggestion that you should learn the basics of all 3. basics of one of them would be good enough.